# Segregating 3 different Characters in an array

Tags: character

Can anyone help me with this question?

Q. Segregate R,G,B flag in O(n) and using one variable.
For eg:- R R G B R R B G G R

Output should be: R R R R R G G G B B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the whole list 3 times. each time write only single letter it's 3*n which is o(n)

Comment: Any other way to do it? cuz just passing the list 3 times looks quite trivial

Comment: That the beauty of the solution - it's a trivial one, so the chance of a mistake is small.

Comment: You mean to say that we should the write the list in place or make a separate list?

Comment: you can do both, but using the same list is more tricky and might be more than 3Xn